# Populating depended spinner with two words

Tags: php, android, json

I am having issue with spinner populating from PHP. I have MySQL table with cities and classes. I need to take classes from specific sities. PHP for cities looks like this:

```
{"lista":[{"City":"Beograd"},{"City":"Novi Sad"},{"City":"Kragujevac"}]}
```

and when I try to populate spinner with classes from "Novi Sad" I am getting error in android

```
08-09 09:53:37.762: E/Fail 1(28592): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 50: http://192.168.1.2/test/test.php?city=Novi%20Sad
```

If I call `http://192.168.1.2/test/test.php?grad=Novi%20Sad` in my localhost I am getting `{"lista":[{"Class":"matematika"},{"Class":"informatika"}]}`. If I try to populate spinner with City: Beograd or Kragujevac everything is working fine. I am guessing that problem is in empty space between Novi and Sad.

Url for populating spinner2 from spinner1(Cities):

```
str_grad1=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
String url="http://192.168.1.2/test/test.php?grad="+str_grad1;
```

EDIT: Here is also PHP script

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

$sql = "SELECT Predmet FROM lista where City='".$_GET['grad']."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $rows[] = $row; 
    }

mysqli_close($con);

$arr = array_flip(array_map('serialize', $rows));
$lista = array_map('unserialize', array_flip($arr));
echo json_encode((object) array('lista' => array_values($lista)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you encode `str_grad1` like

```
String url="http://192.168.1.2/test/test.php?grad=" + URLEncoder.encode( str_grad1 );
```

instead of:

```
String url="http://192.168.1.2/test/test.php?grad="+str_grad1;
```

Comment: I get warning that The method encode(String) from the type URLEncoder is deprecated...I am still getting same error when I try to populate spinner.

Comment: Use `URLEncoder.encode( str_grad1, "UTF-8" )` instead. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html. Also, can you show, how are you reading the variable in the PHP code and the value read in PHP.